# Component not re rendering after state changing in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to create a testimonial marquee type component with React useState using an array from another file but my component wont re render after changing the array. It should change after every 2 seconds.

My state is changing correctly according to my console logs. But the component is just not re rendering.

My external data looks something like this :

```js
export const testimonials = [
    {
        img     : "",
        info    : "",
        company : "",
        link    : ""
    },
    {
        img     : "",
        info    : "",
        company : "",
        link    : ""
    },...
```

Not sure if its not re rendering because generalized it looks like this? Thats just a guess though.
[object][object][object]

```js
const Testimonials = ({ classes }) => {
    const [ arr, setArr ] = useState(testimonials);

    const IncrementTestimonials = (arr2) => {
        let el = arr2.shift();
        arr2.push(el);
        setArr(arr2);
        console.log('changed');
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setInterval(() => {
                console.log('changing');
                IncrementTestimonials(arr);
            }, 2000);
        },
        [ arr ]
    );

    return (
      {arr.map((e) => (
            <div className={classes.Card}>
               <p>"{e.info}"</p>
             </div>
       ))}
    );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

arr2 is just a reference to your state, you cannot modify it, you could do something like this:

```
const IncrementTestimonials = () => {
    const arr2 = [...arr];
    let el = arr2.shift();
    arr2.push(el);
    setArr(arr2);
    console.log('changed');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to modify directly the state. Instead you can get the first element if you have `arr2.length > 0`. Then using `.filter()` you can remove the first element by index. Then using the callback option for `setState()`.

Try as the following:

```
const IncrementTestimonials = (arr2) => {
    if (arr2.length > 0) {
       const firstElem = arr2[0];

       const filteredArray = arr2.filter((e, i) => i !== 0);

       setArr(prevArr => filteredArray.concat(firstElem));
    }
};
```

Using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you will have a new array, see from the documentation:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const IncrementTestimonials = () => {
        let arr2 = [...arr]
        let el = arr2.shift();
        arr2.push(el);
        setArr(arr2);
        console.log('changed');
    };

 useEffect(
        () => {
            const timer = setTimeout(() => { // use timeout as after every 2 seconds , your effect will run
                console.log('changing');
                IncrementTestimonials();
            }, 2000);
            return ()=>{
               clearTimeout(timer); 
            }
        },
        [ arr ]
    );

    return (
      {arr.map((e) => (
            <div className={classes.Card}>
               <p>{`${e.info}}`</p> // use string interpolation i.e backticks
             </div>
       ))}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const IncrementTestimonials = (arr2) => {
      let el = arr2.shift();
      arr2.push(el);
      setArr(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2)));
      console.log('changed ' + arr[0].company);
  };
```

Comment: My initial testimonial array is an array of objects would that matter?

Comment: Not really, just wondering if you are trying to get the testimonials dynamically or is already pre-populated.

Comment: yeh they're all pre-populated in another file.

Comment: Just updated my comment, this change will force the array to update the array. The mutation is a problem with arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use spread `...` operator

```
setArr([...arr2])
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).